# Priorities in AngularFire 0.5.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have a collection of articles:

```
var articlesRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/articles");  
$scope.articles = $firebase(articlesRef);
```

I want to add a few articles with a `new Date()` priority:

```
$scope.articles.$add(newArticle1).$priority = new Date();
$scope.articles.$add(newArticle2).$priority = new Date();
$scope.articles.$add(newArticle3).$priority = new Date();
```

- How do I fetch these articles and sort by the Date priority?
- How do I query a range of articles from *X-Date* to *Y-Date*?
- How do I retrieve the values of those priorities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to order posts by time, I recommend *not* using Date() and only rely on `$add`. `$add` automatically creates chronologically ordered lists of items. In the absence of priorities, Firebase automatically orders items by their key names.

To fetch the articles in chronological order, simply use the `orderByPriority` filter, eg: `<ul ng-repeat="article in articles | orderByPriority">`.

Querying a range from a specific data becomes trickier - if you know the key name for the article you want to start the range at, you can just pass that to startAt. `$add` returns a Firebase reference, and you can get the key name via `.name()`.

For example, the following snippet will create a window starting at the article just added and upto 10 articles after it:

```
var justAdded = $scope.articles.$add(newArticle);
var query = ref.startAt(justAdded.name()).limit(10);
```

For a comprehensive solution where you need to be able to query by any time across all articles, you might consider storing a time for each item added via `$add`. I'd again avoid using Date() becaue client-side times cannot be trusted, but instead use Firebase's server side timestamps: https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/servervalue/TIMESTAMP.html which are more reliable. For instance, you might store the time at which a particular article was added so you can later cross-reference a given time with an article ID auto-generated via `$add`.

Comment: But, what is the best way of setting the priority of a snapshot when adding it to a $FirebaseArray? Vanilla API has the `setWithPriority` method, but as far as I know, AngularFire doesn't have an equivalent...